# How to get TimeZone wise local time using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, localtime

i am working with two js library to get browser timezone id and browser local time

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/moment-timezone.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
            alert(tz.name());

            alert(moment.tz(tz.name()).format());
        });
    </script>
```

this below code return perfect timezone id

```
       var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
        alert(tz.name());
```

but this code is not working `alert(moment.tz(tz.name()).format());` not giving user local time.

am i missing something in code? do i need to add any momentjs related other file ?

please guide me. i want to get user local time using moment.js. thanks

### UPDATE Working Version

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jstz.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
    <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
            alert(tz.name());

            var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
            alert(moment.tz('Europe/London').format(format));
            alert(moment.tz(tz.name()).format(format));
        });
    </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the moment i add these two js file then  my code started working 
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.6.0/moment.min.js
http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js

Comment: i just like to know does this data file moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js  has all info for all timezone?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nKUwn/
http://jsfiddle.net/93pEd/1/

Comment: Lost 2 hours searching how to get local zone name from moment_timezone, your solution is working.

Comment: tell me your issue solved or not?

Comment: <script src="js/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js"></script>


<script th:inline="javascript">document.write(toLocalTime(<<TIME IN MILLISECONDS HERE>>));</script>


function toLocalTime(time) {
 if (time <= 0)
  return '';
  
 var m = moment.tz(time, 'America/Chicago'); //CDT
 
 var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
 
 m.tz(tz.name()); // Convert CDT to local time
 
 return m.format('HH:mm:ss');
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution of this case (this is part of the page code):

```js
function toLocalTime(time) {
 if (time <= 0)
  return '';
  
 var m = moment.tz(time, 'America/Chicago'); //CDT
 
 var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
 
 m.tz(tz.name()); // Convert CDT to local time
 
 return m.format('HH:mm:ss');
}
```

```html
<script src="js/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js"></script>

...........

<script th:inline="javascript">document.write(toLocalTime(<<TIME IN MILLISECONDS HERE>>));</script>
```